# Linear dHSIC calculation example

Tags: probability

For some purpose in my research I recently used linear HSIC calculation defined as follows:
$$ \|Y^TX\|_F^2 / (n-1)^2 $$

Which works for two independent variables. Now, I need to calculate HSIC for more than 2 variables, and I encountered dHSIC [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00285.pdf). To be honest, I'm not a huge statistician and I don't fully understand the paper. Can anyone give an example of how to calculate linear dHSIC on 3 independent variables - X, Y, and Z?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the implementation (from the authors) found in the R package [dHSIC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dHSIC/index.html)?

Comment: First, I need to use it in a python script so that won't work. Second, I want to understand the math behind it and not just use it as a black box.

Comment: Cool. For point 1, try translating the R code; yes, no fun but actually it is easy to follow (I have read it myself). For point 2, how's your understanding of RKHS? Literally there is the crux of the issue and how we define a tensor product over them. I would suggest looking into Gretton et al. (2007) [A Kernel Statistical Test of Independence](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2007/hash/d5cfead94f5350c12c322b5b664544c1-Abstract.html) first. It is the same bivariate case and then go for dHSIC. Pfister et al. (2016) is not a trivial paper to just honker down without the mathematical background.